# Continually update and fetch value for an already instantiated class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiprocessing, watchdog

I have a Selenium-based web crawler. The Crawler has a GUI interface and a display that shows the current URL, current crawler depth, and how many files have been downloaded. Typically the crawler uses the requests library to download files. Once the download request is processed, the tally of downloaded files is updated +1.

[image: UI display example]

I recently added in functionality to handle downloads that aren't easily processed through requests. These are mostly files that need to be downloaded via interaction with Javascript elements. I've added a class (`DownloadHandler`) that uses Watchdog to monitor the download directory for added files and perform a function to record each file as it is added. This is working fine, the only problem is I'm having trouble updating the "Downloaded" tally from this class.

Condensed code example below:

```
class DownloadHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_files = 0

    def handle_download(self):
        do_stuff()
        self.new_files += 1
```

The `DownloadHandler` class is accessed by the `Crawler` class:

```
class Crawler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dl_handler = DownloadHandler()
```

The crawler will download new files to the directory and the DownloadHandler will perform the `handle_download` function. However, when I try to access the augmented value of `new_files` from the main Crawler class, the number stays at 0.

```
>>>print(self.dl_handler.new_files)
>>>output: 0
```

What I'm trying to figure out is: how can I continually update and fetch the augmented value of the DownloadHandler's new_files property from the Crawler class that instantiated it?

I hope this makes sense!

Watchdog Code:

```
class DownloadHandler(Observer):
    def __init__(self, temp_dir):
        self.temp_dir = 'PATH'
        self.new_files = 0

    def handle_download(self):
        do_stuff()
        self.new_files += 1

    def monitor_directory(self):
        event_handler = MyHandler(self.temp_dir)
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=self.temp_dir.name, recursive=False)
        observer.start()

class MyHandler(DownloadHandler, FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(temp_dir):
        self.temp_dir = temp_dir
    def on_created(self, event):
        if not re.search(r'.*crdownload$|\.com\.google\.Chrome.*', event.src_path) and event.src_path != self.temp_dir.name:
            try:
                self.handle_download()
            except FileNotFoundError as e:
                pass
```

Comment: Share the code that uses watchdog, on its own your problem is not reproducible. Unless you are using `multiprocessing` library, the counter should increment and accessing it should reflect that.

Comment: I see that `MyHandler` inherits from `DownloadHandler` and `FileSystemEventHandler`, yet its initializer method does not invoke the base classes' initializer methods. Therefore, there is no attribute `self.new_files` created and initialized. Consequently , `self.new_files += 1` must surely fail.